# Is there a way to prevent someone from reinstalling Windows on a PC/Laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, reinstall

Is there a possibility to prevent someone from reinstalling Windows on a personal computer (in my case - a laptop with Windows 10).

I know that replacing the hard drive and resetting bios by removal of the battery will be still possible, but is there an option to block an unwanted reinstallation, or make it at least more complicated?

Comment: Simplest way. Use a firmware password so the boot order cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent reinstalling Windows on your laptop.

1. Keep control of your laptop.
2. Have a very strong Disk and Computer Login (not operating system) password so that 99% of people simply cannot access. You can also have a supervisor password on your BIOS but don't ever forget that. The "login" password protect basic BIOS access. Person cannot access without the password. I know from my own machine.
3. Encrypt if you wish. Be sure you keep the encryption password and credentials.
4. Make sure you are using UEFI and Secure Boot to prevent booting with an unauthorized USB Key.
5. Removing the battery and resetting BIOS died some years back.

So follow steps 1 to 4 and you will be safe. I follow steps 1 to 4 all the time.

Comment: About point 1. - easier said than done, cause I am living 600 kilometers away from the person who wants his laptop secured, and from all the family members - he trusts only me. Are You sure about point 4? I am using UEFI and Secure Boot on both my PCs and it never prevented me from reinstalling Windows on any of them...

Comment: Use steps 2 and 4 any make sure passwords are strong. Yes about point 4. Only a Windows USB can reinstall windows, so make sure about passwords.

Comment: So long as your user turns off the laptop when not using it, and has both passwords set (BIOS and Disk) no one can turn it on and a replacement disk won’t run. So overall fairly easy to secure a laptop.

Comment: Thank You very much!

Comment: Your friend with the laptop should be fine following the overall security approach.

Comment: Regarding #5 no removing the battery hasn't died.  Sometimes its a bit more tricky, like you have to short a jumper, but I can do it on a brand new motherboard.  Now that I have cleared your BIOS I can boot from a USB stick, and format your drive encryption or not. You can have a 1000 digit password and when I dban your hard drive your data is gone.

Comment: It depends on the motherboard. Not all can be jumped this way.